# Java file path and url in Process class

Tags: java, url, process, filepath

How to edit these code to make it work:

```
 String[] var1 = { "\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe" };
 String[] var2 = { "http://google.com" };

 Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process process = runTime.exec("\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" http://google.com");
 Process process2 = runTime.exec(var1,var2);
```

first "process" work fine, but "process2" open default site in IE instead of google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the **var1** is wrong you have a scaped **"** at the begin

it must be:

```
String[] var1 = { "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe" };
```

that is the reason of the exception

Now according to the doc:

[image]

you need to pass in the same array the command to execute and the parameters...

so it must be only

```
Process process2 = runTime.exec(var1);
```

where

```
String[] var1 = { "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe", "http://google.com" };
```

Comment: Tried it before, still default IE site instead google.com

Comment: worked :) thanks, I'm sure I tried it but without comma

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

---

`process` is using the method:

```
public Process exec(String[] cmdarray) throws IOException
```

> Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process.
>   This is a convenience method. An invocation of the form exec(cmdarray)
>   behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation exec(cmdarray, null,
>   null).

---

`process2` is using the method:

```
public Process exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp) throws IOException
```

> Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process
>   with the specified environment. This is a convenience method. An
>   invocation of the form exec(cmdarray, envp) behaves in exactly the
>   same way as the invocation exec(cmdarray, envp, null).

---

Try doing:

```
String var1 = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe";
String var2 = "http://google.com";
Process process2 = runTime.exec({var1,var2});
```